# how to sort array in java and convert to string

Tags: java

```
public class Sort {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int num[] = { -1, 11, 3, 34, 5, 99, 10 };
    int length = num.length;
    int temp = 0;
    int jj;
    String printinstring ="";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j =1; j < length; j++) {
            if (num[j-1] > num[j]) {
                temp = num[j-1];
                num[j-1]=num[j];
                num[j]=temp;
            }

        }




    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.out.println(num[i]);
        printinstring=printinstring+Integer.toString(num[i]);

    }

    System.out.println(printinstring);
}
}
```

the out put is

```
-1
3
5
10
11
34
99
-13510113499
```

if we change <
then out put is 99---

Answer (score 1):

There is already a predefined library function [sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29), no need to write one.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    System.out.println(num[i]);
    printinstring=printinstring+Integer.toString(num[i]);

}
```

should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
        printinstring = printinstring + " ";
    }
    printinstring = printinstring + Integer.toString(num[i]);
}
```

or more concisely

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
        printinstring += " ";
    }
    printinstring += num[i];
}
```

or even

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    printinstring += ((i > 0) ? " " : "") + num[i];
}
```

---

But @Mahesh is right.  There is no need to implement sort yourself.  Use the existing library method.